# How can I send CustomUserId to Appinsight by writing code in .netcore 2.2?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I created app-insight application in azure to keep track of metrics. Everything looks fine and easy to see Req/Res.I did below steps:
adding appsettings.json:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
"InstrumentationKey": "xxxx-7a49-4bc1-yyyy-kkkkk"
},
```

And adding UseApplicationInsights in Program.cs

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

but I want to send something to appinsight and see as a column when I write 
kusto query.

is there any way like below stuff:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .ChangeValue("UserId",Httphelper.GetCurrentUserId)
        .AddColumn("MyCustomField", Httphelper.Something)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Can I do that or any way to send or modify existed value? I Tried to find any article about it but I couldn't satisfied solution.

Comment: You can add the customuserid as a custom property.

Comment: Can you give me a link for that? or answer with sample. I'II mark as a correct answer cus you are great with this advise.

Comment: Yeah, I posted an answer. Please let me know if you have more issues about that:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as a custom property via [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

In the sample code, you just need a few modification to add a property like below:

```
  public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
      telemetry.Properties["customuserid"] = "your_id";
    }

 }
```

For how to register the ITelemetryInitializer to asp.net core project, please refer to this section "**ASP.NET Core/ Worker Service apps: Load your initializer**" in the above doc. A screenshot as below:

[image]

After you add the above code, then every telemetry data will include the custom property. Then in your kusto query, you can take use of this property.

Comment: telemetry.Properties["customuserid"] = "your_id"; return me error :: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ITelemetry' does not contain a definition for 'Properties' and no accessible extension method 'Properties' accepting a first argument of type 'ITelemetry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TelemetryApp1 C:\Projects\PlayGround\Tests\TelemetryApp1\RequestScopedTelemetryInitializer.cs 15 Active

Comment: @loki You need to check whether the incoming `telemetry` implements `ISupportProperties`

Comment: @loki, can you solve it by Peter Bons comment? If not, please let me know.